# Wordpress custom URLs and templates

Tags: wordpress, templates, url

Easy question: how do I create a custom URL in WordPress without creating a page first?

I know about template inheritance and I know that I can always specify a custom template in page-page_name.php.  But instead of creating a page, I just want the custom template and the URL.

So if I go to http://mysite.com/custom_page_1 I want to be able to modify a template for this link and this link only without creating an empty page called Custom Page 1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you worried about publishing a page before it should be? Make a drat of that page and preview it.

If not, why cant you create the page?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, URLs are essentially permalinks that are generated by rewriting the default `domain.com/?p=x`, where x is the post ID. So unless there is something in the database that has an ID (post, page, category, user id, etc) then there is nothing to rewrite.